# Clearing build cache in angular

Tags: caching, gitlab, angular-cli

In angular 13 default build caching was introduced.

I want to use it in my CD/CI gitlab pipelines but I can't find any information about when the cache should be cleared.

For every merge request, I want to build my app and run some tests.
It is safe to use the same cached directory for each MR, no matter what was changed?
If not, what should be the key for the cache?

I didn't find anything about it in angular docs.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow some best practices as illustrated in GitLab documentation, whose runners do have a cache management.

See "[Good caching practices](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#good-caching-practices)"

```yaml
test-job:
  stage: build
  cache:
    - key:
        files:
          - Gemfile.lock
      paths:
        - vendor/ruby
    - key:
        files:
          - yarn.lock
      paths:
        - .yarn-cache/
  script:
    - bundle install --path=vendor
    - yarn install --cache-folder .yarn-cache
    - echo Run tests...
```

In this example, you indicate to `yarn` where the cache folder (from the runner) is.

In your case (Angular cache, as requested in [issue 21545](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21545)), if you use a GitLab runner cache, you can [clear said cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#clearing-the-cache) when you want.